# Trying to append arrays to highcharts ( jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I have done all my coding in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n06v3dh2/)

I have kept alert for all the arrays. MARKET[0], MARKET[1](http://jsfiddle.net/n06v3dh2/), MARKET[2], MARKET[3], MARKET[4], MARKET[5], MARKET[6], MARKET[7]

They are coming in alert. But when I have given the same arrays in Highcharts code near series, the arrays are not been appended and the values are showing zero in the graph.
Why the arrays are not appending to the highchart code? I have done all my coding, only appending to highcharts is left.

I have used area-stacked chart.
This is my highchart code

```
 $('#container2').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'area'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'molname'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Top Competitors'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: DATES[0],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        title: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Mkt Share'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value ;
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            lineColor: '#666666',
            lineWidth: 1,
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#666666'
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: mname0,
        data: MARKETS[0]
    }, {
        name: mname1,
        data: MARKETS[1]
    },
    {
        name: mname2,
        data: MARKETS[2]
    },
    {
        name: mname3,
        data: MARKETS[3]
    },
    {
        name: mname4,
        data: MARKETS[4]
    },
    {
        name: mname5,
        data: MARKETS[5]
    },
    {
        name: mname6,
        data: MARKETS[6]
    },  
    {
        name: mname7,
        data: MARKETS[7]
    }
        ]
```

Anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the values in your `MARKET` array are strings. They must be converted to numbers. In your case they are floats, so for example using the `parseFloat` function.

For example changing from:

```
MARKETS[0].push(findDataForMonth(mname0, month) || 0.0);
// ...
```

To ([JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/n06v3dh2/1/)):

```
MARKETS[0].push(parseFloat(findDataForMonth(mname0, month)) || 0.0);
// ...
```

This type of error might be easier to spot with `console.log` instead of `alert` as you can see the difference between a string and a number.